# Rails: Which is the most recommended directory to put CSV files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Which is the best directory to place CSV files which I  want to use for database seeding? Is it the `tmp` ?

I am using this gem: https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv

Comment: I usually keep them in /lib, in their own folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I put all seed data in /db/… (usually /db/seeds), that way they're nicely separated from any code files and also obvious as to what the .csv files are to other programmers new to your codebase.

Answer (score 3):

I would not put them in the tmp folder, since by definition, thinks that are inside this folder are not meant to stay. I'd also put it in the `/lib` folder as Ralph King suggested.